# rail state machine not working for one state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

state with ? not working only for `scheduled` state

```
email = Email.find(1)
```

when email.state is failed

```
email.failed?   => true
email.state?(:failed)   => true
```

When email state is scheduled

```
email.state?(:scheduled) => true 
email.scheduled?   => false
```

very strange email.scheduled?   => false

Comment: Maybe send a bug report to the Rails team?

Comment: Try `reload`ing the object.

Comment: using in the Serializer @SebastianPalma